# How do I use the morpher modifier in 3dsmax to morph into several targets simultaneously?

Tags: animation, 3dsmax, face

I have a 3D-Face from Facegen here including all necessary phenomes' positions. But these targets are separated into upper, lower teeth, sock and eyes. How do I combine them for the face to morph into each facial position at once?

Comment: what your looking for is a facial rigging tutorial, it would be very difficult to answer this with just text so here is a link to a comprehensive video tutorial http://www.digitaltutors.com/11/training.php?pid=176

Answer (score 1):

Simply clone a copy of your character's mesh, add a morpher modifier, and then apply all of the morphs you want combined into a separate morph channel. Set all of the morphs to 100%. Then collapse the character mesh's stack and tadaa, you have a single morph target with all of the morphs combined. Now apply this morph target to your original character and delete the cloned mesh if you don't need it anymore.